# looping horizontally Map<String, List<String>> and setting variables of javabean

Tags: java, hashmap

I've a map implementation of `Map<String, List<String>>` and a javabean class having member variables of map keys.

Java bean class:

```
@Data
public class SplunkConfig {

  private String parameter1;
  private String parameter2;
  private String parameter3;

}
```

Map :

```
{host=["abc","def","ghi","jkl"],count=["1","3","4","5"],time=["2017-02-03","2017-02-04","2017-02-04","2017-02-05"]}
```

And I want to set variables in `SplunkConfig` class like below :

```
SplunkConfig sc = new SplunkConfig();
sc.setParameter1("abc");
sc.setParameter2("1");
sc.setParameter3("2017-02-03");
sc.setParameter1("def");
sc.setParameter2("3");
sc.setParameter3("2017-02-04");
..so on..
```

I do have an array list of beans to store the Java beans once the variables are set.

So, I've to loop through the map values one by one of each key and set the javabean member variables as shown above.

Can someone please let me know how to loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you use 'setParameter1' twice, the first one is useful because it will erase the first operation, it's really what you do ?

Comment: @azro , yeah I know about that. I've a list to store beans as soon as the variables are set. Hope I'm clear now.

Comment: I've added it to show how I want loop to be. Thanks

Comment: Not sure that I understand your map, host is the key and the value is a List of two elements: count and time? That is `count = map.get(host).get(0); time = map.get(host).get(1)`?

Comment: Nope. host, count and time are keys.. and each of them have a lost of strings. Hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's call the map with the data **mapWithData**, and its content is:

```
{"host"=["abc","def","ghi","jkl"], "count"=["1","3","4","5"], "time"=["2017-02-03","2017-02-04","2017-02-04","2017-02-05"]}
```

Note that the keys are now strings within double quotes.

Now, let's create a list of **SplunkConfig** objects from that map:

```
int numberOfElements = mapWithData.get("host").size();
List<SplunkConfig> config = new ArrayList<SplunkConfig>();

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfElements; i++) {
  SplunkConfig sc = new SplunkConfig();
  sc.setParameter1(mapWithData.get("host").get(i));
  sc.setParameter2(mapWithData.get("count").get(i));
  sc.setParameter3(mapWithData.get("time").get(i));

  config.add(sc);
}
```

It is better practice to call **parameter1** in a descriptive name - **host**. Same for parameter2 and 3.

You can finally use or return **config**.

Comment: I actually wanted to loop dynamically without giving `host`, `count` and `time` keys in case if I need to add a new variable in `SplunkConfig` class. But, somehow managed to pull the data with `reflection` api. Many Thanks for your answer.